# List items being ignored or not detected

Tags: python, loops, types, attributes

I am learning Python as my first language, and working on the Old Maid game from How to Think like a Computer Scientist. My code was going into an infinite loop and I can't figure out why so I posted on stack overflow. I was asked to isolate the problem and post less code (good advice) which I have now done.

The Problem: Originally, `remove_matches` would correctly detect and remove matches for all cards objects, except for Aces. Now that I have duplicated the problem on a smaller scale, it doesn't seem to be removing matches for any card ranks. In the following example, I used matching Aces and matching Kings. Neither match is being detected.

```
class Card:
suite_list = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
rank_list = ["narf", "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
# "narf" is being used as a placeholder for the zeroith item, to allow
# card#'s to match the index #'s

def __init__(self, suite = 0, rank = 0):
    self.suite = suite
    self.rank = rank

def __str__(self):
    return self.rank_list[self.rank]+" of "+self.suite_list[self.suite]



class Deck:
def __init__ (self):
    self.cards = []
    for suite in range (4):
        for rank in range (1, 14):
            self.cards.append(Card(suite, rank))

def __str__ (self):
    s = " "
    for i in range (len(self.cards)):
        s = s + " "*i + str(self.cards[i]) + "\n"
    return s

def remove_card(self,card):
    if card in self.cards:
        self.cards.remove(card)
        return True
    else:
        return False


class Hand(Deck):
def __init__ (self, name = " "):
    self.cards = []
    self.name = name

def __str__(self):
    s = "Hand "+ self.name
    return s+ " contains\n" + Deck.__str__(self)

def remove_matches(self):
    count = 0
    for card in self.cards:
        match = Card(3 - card.suite, card.rank)
        print card, " matches ", match
        if match in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            self.cards.remove(match)
            print "Hand %s: %s matches %s" % (self.name, card, match)
            count = 1
    return count

Joes_hand = Hand("Joe")
Joes_hand.cards = [Card(1,1), Card(2,1), Card(1,13), Card(2,13)]
print Joes_hand
Joes_hand.remove_matches()
print
print Joes_hand
```

---

`Joes_hand = Hand()`

First, I create a player named Joe, he has no card objects in his hand yet.

`Joes_hand.cards = [Card(1,1), Card(2,1), Card(1,13), Card(2,13)]`

Now I have assigned 4 cards to Joe.

`print Joes_hand`

Then I printed Joe's hand so we can see the cards he has.

`Hand Joe contains
 Ace of Diamonds
 Ace of Hearts
  King of Diamonds
   King of Hearts`

`Joes_hand.remove_matches()`

This is where I run into a problem. `remove_matches` is supposed to remove cards that match by rank and color. This is possible because rank and suite are built in attributes of my `Card` objects. I added a print statement inside the `remove_matches` method:
`print card, " matches ", match`, for the purpose of proving that the code is able to identify what a match IS. But for some reason it fails to detect the match, even though it knows what to look for. Therefore, none of the statements following the if statement: `if match in self.cards:` are being executed.

Output:

`Ace of Diamonds  matches  Ace of Hearts
Ace of Hearts  matches  Ace of Diamonds
King of Diamonds  matches  King of Hearts
King of Hearts  matches  King of Diamonds`

Finally I print Joe's hand again to show that none of the cards have been removed.

`print
print Joes_hand`

`Hand Joe contains
 Ace of Diamonds
 Ace of Hearts
  King of Diamonds
   King of Hearts`

And here is another look at `remove_matches`:

```
def remove_matches(self):
    count = 0
    for card in self.cards:
        match = Card(3 - card.suite, card.rank)
        print card, " matches ", match
        if match in self.cards:
            self.cards.remove(card)
            self.cards.remove(match)
            print "Hand %s: %s matches %s" % (self.name, card, match)
            count = 1
    return count
```

I'm sorry my post is long, I tend to over-explain but I want to make sure that I'm sharing all of my information. Am I missing something obvious? I've been struggling with this for days. Any thoughts would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: A [mcve] (Note the Minimal) would be nice...

Comment: @Julien Okay, thanks for the link! I am trying to write a short version of the code that hopefully isolates the problem.

Comment: Also, I've edited the code, and I believe I've reproduced the problem here.

Comment: I'm sure it's no surprise to you, but about all I've concluded so far is that your main check statement, **if match in self.cards** in remove_matches, is failing for aces.  I have no idea why ... yet ... and I have to go do *other stuff* now.

Comment: @Prune Thank you for having a look! I will try to get a working (truncated) version posted tomorrow after work.